# Run Geoserver in offline mode using netbeans

Tags: maven, offline, geoserver

I am trying to run geoserver in offline mode by downloading all the required jars and the whole project setup using netbeans.But when I run the Start.java file  it gives long path error( CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long).

I dont want to use maven for that as I want this to be run in offline mode.

Comment: Please post your code with "required jars".

Comment: use `mvn -o` for offline use

Comment: I have downloaded all the required jars,but while compiling it gives long path error. As winodows command path length is limited and the jar files are around 1500.  It gives error "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long"

Comment: Can you put it in a path that is shorter?  Take out some sub folders?